# Get two linq queries into one listbox

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get the values of two LINQ queries in to one listbox. Currently I have it going in to two separate listboxe's side by side so it works but is not optimal. The data is essentially a list of names and a list of values that goes with those names.

```
        var getTotalsColumn = from p in dataTable select p.TOTALS;

        foreach (var totals in getTotalsColumn)
        {
            employeeByIspListBox.Items.Add(totals);

        }
            var getNamesColumn = from p in dataTable select p.NAME;

        foreach (var names in getNamesColumn)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(names);
        }
```

How can I combine this to put for example `John Doe : 21` into one listbox.
Both Totals and Name returns type String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you just want:

```
var items = dataTable.Select(p => string.Format("{0} : {1}", p.NAME, p.TOTALS));
listBox1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
```

Comment: As a side note to this. What if I wanted to sort the items in the list box by the numbers in the TOTALS column? I think I would have to declare the array ahead of time and use the Orderby method? Any hints?

Comment: @Nabbic: No, you'd just use `dataTable.OrderBy(p => p.TOTALS).Select(p => ...)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try this. I am getting unexpected results from `var items = dataTable.OrderBy(p => p.TOTALS).Select(p` `=>string.Format("{0}: {1}", p.NAME, p.TOTALS));` I have numbers 1 through 16 and it returned from top to bottom 1,10,12,13,14,16,2,3,4,6,7,8. I am thinking because they aren't actually ints they are strings?

Comment: @Nabbic: Do you mean the type of `TOTALS` is `string`? Ick! Try to fix that - this is naturally numeric data, right? So have it in a numeric type. Otherwise you'll need to parse it...

Comment: I thought as much and was on my TODO list I will move it to a higher priority on my TODO list. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your query:

```
var values = from p in dataTable
             select p.NAME + " : " + p.TOTALS;

listBox1.Items.AddRange(values.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    foreach (var p in dataTable )
    {
        employeeByIspListBox.Items.Add(p.NAME + " : " + p.TOTALS);

    }
```